# Mathematica In[1]/Out[1]

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am a new Mathematica user. I have a simple question: Every time I open a new Mathematica notebook the input entry number does not start from In[1] but follows from the number of the last input in the last Mathematica notebook I work. It follows each variable I assign in one notebook will pass automatically to the other notebook. Does anyone know I can start from In[1] each time I open a new Mathematica notebook, and how to clear all the variables I assigned from the previous notebooks? Thank you very much.

Comment: There exists a Stack Exchange site for questions regarding Mathematica: [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com) - You may find more luck over there. **But make sure to check out the help center for that site** before asking to ensure this is on-topic for that site.

Comment: The numbers are determined by the kernel. The only way to reset them is to restart the kernel. Is there a reason why you want the numbers to start from 1 in a new notebook?

Comment: @Rohit Thank you for replying. I have figured out the number issue. But my concern is if I am working on two notebooks together, the variable I assign for one notebook will automatically pass to the other. For example, let x = 1 for the first notebook and x = 2 for the second, then when I go back to the first notebook x is no longer 1 but becomes 2.

Comment: @Vince Thank you very much. I appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: FYI [new kernel for notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43900/new-kernel-for-notebook)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The kernel state (variables, definitions, etc) is not local to a notebook. It is shared between all notebooks.  Thus `k` in `In[k]` refers to the `k`th input *in the current session* not in the current notebook.

It is possible to make the state *appear* local to notebook by setting Evaluation -> Notebook's Default Context -> Unique to This Notebook.  This won't isolate notebooks completely, as there is still only a single kernel running. But for most common use cases it is adequate.  An `x` variable in the first notebook will appear distinct from `x` in the second notebook.